# Dynamic and Responsive Wordpress Image on page based on Featured Image

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Alright so I looked through here and tried to find a solution to this, and I found some php that came up twice as an answer, but it isn't working for me, so here's the problem.

I have a custom wordpress theme. Under the navbar, I want to put a dynamic image based on that page's featured image. The image needs to be responsive and spread across the width of the page, much like you'd imagine a responsive header image to function. I can handle the responsive css bit and put the image in a div when I get to pulling it, but the image isn't even pulling.

Here's the code that came up twice as an answer on Stack Overflow:

```
  <img src="<?php $img=wp_get_attachment_thumb_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID)); echo $img[0]; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"/>
```

It isn't working. The php string is not pulling the thumbnail url and the only output in the console is the alt information wrapped in an img tag. I don't know if it has to do with the code being in the header.php, but any advice would be great.

Comment: Shouldn't `echo get_post_thumbnail($post->ID);` work here? Am I missing something in the question?

Comment: Have you declared `global $post` anywhere on the template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this to show post thumbnails within the loop. You can also pass an elseif statement to show nothing if no image is uploaded or show a placeholder image. Hope that helps!

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>

    <?php the_post_thumbnail('PLACE-CUSTOM-SIZE-HERE-OR-OMIT-TO-USE-ORIGINAL-SIZE'); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
if ( has_post_thumbnail()) {
    $featureImage = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'feature' );
    $featureImage = $featureImage[0];
?>   
<div id="feature" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $featureImage; ?>')">
<? } else { ?>
<div id="feature">
<? } ?>
```

This is how I have accomplished this in the past.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just going to leave this here in case this is causing your issue.

From the doc page: [get_post_thumbnail_id()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_thumbnail_id)

> Note: To enable featured images, see post thumbnails, the current
>   theme must include add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );